# Kafka replicas not in sync once a host is replaced

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Hello Kafka/Zookeeper users,

My team has a kafka cluster which works in conjunction with Apache zookeeper. The kafka is hosted on EC2. For any number of reasons, the EC2 host can go down and be replaced by a new host. The new host has a **different broker id** as compared to previous one (id generated by AWS, not us). 
At this point, zookeeper still has the old state where previous host was replica of some partitions.
Although leader re-election happened successfully, the new replacement host was not utilized in any way as leader or replica.

The kafka documentation talks about 'broker coming up again' after sometime, but in EC2 world host is permanently replaced.

> In distributed systems terminology we only attempt to handle a "fail/recover" model of failures where nodes suddenly cease working and then later recover (perhaps without knowing that they have died).

I understand the reason for that. Zookeeper contains state of each partition. That state contains the old dead host as leader and/or follower. When new host comes up, this state is not getting updated to include new host, until we manually run a command to set replicas.

**Is there a way kafka can automatically utilize the new broker as leader or ISR?**

This is causing lot of operational burden on our team to manually assign new broker as replica and trigger 'preferred leader election'.

Comment: Did you fix this situations? I still can't use new broker for ISR or a leader thoght it is given a broker ID. Can we fix this by setting minimum isr number?

Answer (score 1):

Preferred leader election can be triggered automatically by turning on config `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` and tuning `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage`.

However, the problem you are facing is that:

> new servers will not automatically be assigned any existing data
>   partitions, so unless partitions are moved to them they won't be doing
>   any work until new topics are created.

Seems you have to figure out a scheme that is able to automatically execute `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` script whenever a replacement occurs. No purely-automatic scheme is offered out of box.

Comment: Thanks for the info!
We have `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` turned on. But this still requires us to specify new broker id as first entry in 'replica list', wherever we need it to be leader for the partition.
I guess we will have to figure out a way to run the script which does above. May be add lifecycle hooks in auto scaling group